# Dynamic percentage change with filters in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that have ID, date, type of injuries. I am trying to Find the percentage of each affected body part with the ability to filter the year. I used the following Measures:

```
INJURIES COUNT = 
IF(
    ISBLANK ( COUNT( 'Injuries'[ID] ) ), 
    0, 
    COUNT( ( 'Injuries'[ID]) )
)

Injuries percentage = 
DIVIDE(
    Injuries[INJURIES COUNT], 
    CALCULATE(
        Injuries[INJURIES COUNT], 
        ALLSELECTED()
    )
    ,0
)
```

When I show the data in a table it works just fine even when I filter the year:
[image: Data in table looks Ok]

When I try to use it in a card visual it only show me 100% even if I filtered the body part and the year:
[image: Percentage on Card visual]

How can I fix it? I tried many different solutions but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this below measure (For CARD presentation only)-

```
Injuries percentage = 
DIVIDE(
    Injuries[INJURIES COUNT], 
    CALCULATE(
        Injuries[INJURIES COUNT], 
        ALL(Injuries)
    )
    ,0
)
```

Comment: It work but it uses the grand total rather than the filtered total.. For example if I used the same filters used above it show me 3.18% which is 36/1131 rather than 36/193 (filtered total).. 1131 is the total number of rows without filter. Is it possible to adjust this?

Comment: use ALLEXCEPT(tablename,columnname) and provide list of columns you wants to exlude from list.

Comment: replace All(Injuries) with All(Injuries[Body Part])